# Imprimir texto de colores en python

Tags: python

Hola soy nuevo en estoy de python y no se bien como puedo imprimir texto de colores en la terminal de windows.

¿Alguien sabe como? Por favor ayúdenme.

Comment: colorama https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es cambiar el color de las cadenas en el CMD de Windows, puedes utilizar el módulo **colorama** que funciona en windows.

Es muy simple de usar:

```
from colorama import init
#Hace que despues de cada cadena vuelva a estar en el color por defecto
init(autoreset=True) 
print(Fore.RED + 'Texto en Rojo')
print('Texto en color por defecto')
```

Tiene dos opciones, Fore para el color de texto, y Back para el color de background.

Estos son los que trae por defecto:

Fore: BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE, RESET.
Back: BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE, RESET.

Sin embargo, puedes consultar toda la documentación oficial [aquí](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) donde te explican muchas mas cosas, incluso como usar mas colores:

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo este link te puede ayudar:
https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/09/dar-color-las-salidas-en-la-consola.html

por ejemplo:

```
print(chr(27)+"[1;33m"+"1 para la negrilla y 33m para amarrill")
```

O también se puede con:

```
print("\033[4;35m"+"4 para negrilla \033 para subrayar y 4 para color morado")
```

Puedes mirar la paleta de colores.

Comment: Por desgracia este mecanismo no sirve en la consola de Windows, que es lo que el usuario pedía